# Can't install a modern Perl from source

Tags: perl, installation

Fedora 14

```
$ uname -a
Linux giles 2.6.35.13-92.fc14.i686 #1 SMP Sat May 21 17:39:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 
GNU/Linux
```

Trying to install a modern Perl (anything greater than 5.12.0 has this problem for me) from source fails. Here's what I try:

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/J/JE/JESSE/perl-5.14.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf perl-5.14.1.tar.gz
cd perl-5.14.1
sh Configure -d
make
```

And I always (slightly different depending on the version) end up with an error message like this after some time:

```
Running Makefile.PL in ext/attributes
../../miniperl -I../../lib Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=perl INSTALLMAN1DIR=none   
INSTALLMAN3DIR=none PERL_CORE=1 LIBPERL_A=libperl.a
Writing Makefile for attributes
Writing MYMETA.yml
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/perl-5.14.1/ext/attributes'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/perl-5.14.1/ext/attributes'
Making all in ext/attributes
make all PERL_CORE=1 LIBPERL_A=libperl.a
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/perl-5.14.1/ext/attributes'
cp attributes.pm ../../lib/attributes.pm
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `ExtUtils/xsubpp', needed by `attributes.c'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/perl-5.14.1/ext/attributes'
Unsuccessful make(ext/attributes): code=512 at make_ext.pl line 463.
make: *** [ext/attributes/pm_to_blib] Error 25
```

Any thoughts as to how I can get past this? I've tried with perlbrew and it fails in the same ways. My system has 5.12.3 installed so I know it must be possible and I can install 5.8.X without a problem (by hand and with perlbrew).

**Update**
Here is my full configure output: http://pastebin.com/4R8rpq8M

And here is my full make output: http://pastebin.com/NJdd7X21

Comment: crossposted: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=905532

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to P5P I was able to track it down to my environment. I had the following line in my `.bashrc` file

```
export GREP_OPTIONS="--exclude-from ~/.grep_excludes --color"
```

Seems that was excluding things during the build and the color option was throwing something else off. Removing that fixed the problem and the build completed. It did have a single test failure in `t/porting/exec-bit.t` but that seems safe to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I see at http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-873787-start-0.html:

> Solved - corrupt /usr/bin/ls
>
> Linked to /bin/ls and all built OK

If this is in fact the problem, I would like to hear more about the ls that didn't work.

Comment: hmm; does just restarting make help?  if you are using make -j, does removing the -j help?  Is it just one machine or several?

Comment: I'm not using `-j`, I'm using the exact same commands I've listed above with not variation. And no, re-running `make` doesn't change anything, it just fails faster :)

Answer (score 0):

`xsubpp` ships with the source distribution -- you'll find it in `dist/ExtUtils-ParseXS/lib/ExtUtils/xsubpp`. Maybe a workaround is to copy it yourself to `lib/ExtUtils/xsubpp` and continue running `make`?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here:
http://www.techsutram.com/2011/02/opensuse-113-and-compiling-perl-5123.html

I was trying to compile perl v5.24.2 and had the exact same bug
ODBM_File.xs:153: error: too few arguments to function âdbmcloseâ
make[1]: *** [ODBM_File.o] Error 1

I edited the file /ext/ODBM_File/ODBM_File.xs at line 153 and replaced dbmclose(); ==> dbmclose(db);

After this change make test ran without any issues and 100% of the tests succeeded and make install also worked subsequently.

This error appears to be system dependant because I built the exact same version on another system without any issues.